# Dash after page title

Tags: pages, wp-admin

In the "Pages" section of the WordPress admin panel, after some of the page titles, I see these long dashes and a note(s) of some kind: "Privacy Policy Page", "Front Page, Elementor", etc.

1. What are these "notes"?
2. How do I edit them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit them, and they're not notes stored on a post

- If you set a page in settings as the front page, `Front page` will be shown so it's easier to identify that page
- The same is true if you choose a page to be your privacy policy
- Elementor may add the word Elementor but you need to ask Elementor support for the reason as 3rd party plugin support is off topic here